# Brand new capicola lunch meat slimy?

Tags: meat

Bought a pack of capicola from the store today and when I went to make a sandwich with it, I noticed a slimy texture on all the slices and in the packaging. The expiration date isn't until January 2024 and it smells completely fine, I even gave a slice a little lick and it tasted fine. Is it safe to eat or should I return it and get a refund?

Comment: AFAIK none of these cured meats should ever be slimy... Perhaps it was stored incorrectly at the store, in warm conditions...